# Git correct switching between branches

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

So I have two branches on git: `develop` and `release`. I have been using the `develop` branch until now. I just made a commit to the `develop` branch which I want to be available in the `release` branch. How do I do it? I am a little confused here.

1) Does this automatically happen when I do 
`git checkout -b release`

2) To switch back to the `develop` branch, I can just do a checkout, right? or do I need to do a merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options for making a commit on one branch available to another -- which you choose depends on how you want your history to look, later.

1. A **merge** will create a commit on the `release` branch that has two parents: the tip of `develop` and the former tip of `release`. `release` will then have all of the work from `develop` and `release`. To merge `develop` into `release`, make sure you have a clean working copy, and run `git checkout release`, then `git merge develop`.
2. You can also **cherry-pick** individual commits that were made from `develop` on top of `release`. Cherry-picking creates a new commit on `release` that performs the exact changes that were done in a commit you name. This is useful if you've done a bunch of work on `develop`, but you only want one or two things brought over. To cherry-pick, look at `git log`, copy the sha hash that names the commit you want, and run `git checkout release`, then `git cherry-pick <commit hash>`.
3. If you need to move some big range of commits from one to the other, you can use **rebase --onto**. It's a bit more advanced, but you can [read about it](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#More-Interesting-Rebases) if you're curious.

To answer your follow-on questions:

1. Nope! The general purpose of `git checkout` is to *make your working copy look like a thing that you name*. When you run `git checkout release`, git will change the actual files in your working copy to the state that was last committed to `release`. Checkout doesn't change existing branches. (Also, you don't need the `-b` if `release` already exists; `checkout -b` is a convenient shortcut to create and checkout a branch in one shot.)
2. Along the same lines, to switch back, all you'd need to do is `git checkout develop` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring changes from one branch to another, you have to do a merge.

Comment: Or a cherry-pick, or some similar operation, yes.